# Antd Form.List sort fields declaratively

Tags: reactjs, list, forms, antd

I have a Form.List following the [documentation example](https://ant.design/components/form#components-form-demo-dynamic-form-item) from ant design.

How to make the form items always sorted based on their value, and **stay sorted on each key stroke**?

The internal state is a list of dates. I tried this technique but it doesn't work:

```js
<Form.List>
  {(fields) => (
    <div>
      {[...fields]
        .sort((a,b) => form.getFieldValue(a.name).getTime() > form.getFieldValue(b.name).getTime() ? 1 : -1)
        .map((field) => (
          <Form.Item {...field}>
            <Input />
          </Form.Item>
      ))}
    </div>
  )}
</Form.List>
```

Comment: fields array contains objects with the following keys: `name` & `key`. You need to create the new fields list with dates then sort it or in sort function get date value at each index then use getTime. `[...fields].sort((a, b) => (form.getFieldValue(a.name)?.getTime() > form.getFieldValue(b.name)?.getTime() ? 1 : -1)).map(...)`.

Comment: Ah yes, the snippet is false. That's how I wrote it, using `form.getFieldValue`, and it doesn't work (it gives inconsistent results). I'll update the question.

Comment: In your form list, may be some of date values are missing